# error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) Xcode 11.3

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new to `iOS development.`
When I build my project, I see this building error.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
How do you use "-v" to see invocation?
**I am using Xcode 11.3 Thanks**

[image]

Comment: Maybe Possible duplicate file in your project generate this error. Remove duplicate file or File with same Name and Clean and build.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you only have one copy of Alibaba auth SDK in your workspace

Comment: let me try. Thanks